# iPhone dev: UIWebView Youtube crash. Can I surround it with a try catch?

Tags: iphone, crash, youtube

Im integrating a youtube video in my iPhone application. 
[this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679685/problem-loading-youtube-videos) describes how to integrate it (via a UIWebView), the warning message and the crash, but its unanswered.
In my case the crash only happens from time to time (I think it could be when the user is too quick clicking on the "play" icon) so I want to wrap the error around a try catch and avoid the application from crashing.

Is it possible?

Where do I put the try catch statement? since I dont have control once the user is interaction with the UIWebView.

thanks in advance 
Gonso

Answer (score 0):

If you unload a web view while it's still loading you'll get a crash - it sounds like this might be your problem. Calling `-stopLoading` fixes it.

Comment: Sorry it is still crash. '-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{

 [webView stopLoading];
 webView.delegate=nil;

 [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}'